# Storing information about a user Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, web-applications

I am looking for a way to store users information in a Spring MVC web application. For example I have this method:

```
public int getUserId() throws NumberFormatException, SQLException{

    //Create the connection and the statement   
    Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection(); 
    Statement statement = conn.createStatement();

    //Result set for getting/executing the query
    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username='UserHere'");

    while(rs.next()){
        return Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("user_id"));
    }

    //Return the results
    return -1;
}
```

Through out the web application I am calling this method to get the usersId, I am just looking for a way to call this once, once called it stores it in a variable/place that I can access globally through the Web app?

Maybe on the homepage load I could have a != check to some object referencing this information, if it has not been created, it will be created. This will occur once until the next use.

Thanks

Comment: Unrelated tip use a `JdbcTemplate` instead of trying to work with a plain `DataSource` etc. Second read reference guide chapter about caching .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add this as a variable on the session

```
@RequestMapping(..)
public String controllerMethod(HttpSession session) {
    session.addAttribute("userid", getUserId());
    ...
}
```